# Why was my game, which doesn't collect any data, doesn't have ads, just a very simple game rejected due to security reasons?

Tags: unity-game-engine, publish, google-play-console

[[[[Here are some screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kng4C.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogjjR.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9yll.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9MkE.png)

I tried going to Google play console ---> app consent---> Data types. But I didn't know what to change

I selected "No" for "Does your app collect any of the required data types?"

A stack overflow posts says that I should change this to "yes" but when I did I didn't know what to select. My app doesn't collect any information it doesn't have ads and is completely offline, it's a game.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Unity bundles Unit Ads by default in your project event though you don't use it. I'm not sure if that's the case with your game, but you can look into Package Manager and see if you have Unity Ads installed and uninstall it (This happened to me). Also check if Unity Analytics is there and remove it if you don't use it.

After doing this, the rest of the work should be actually completing the data form accurately. Just tick the boxes that match what you think your game is doing data-wise.